# Cloning Playonlinux Virtual Drives

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I have a virtual drive on Playonlinux with some application which only allows one instance of itself to run. However, I'd like to run several of its instances. For this, I am planning to create multiple virtual drives in Playonlinux and install that application in all of them.

A faster method however would be to install that application in one of the drive, and then just clone that drive as many times as we wish. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for me, hope it does for you.

1. click open the directory on drive you wish do duplicate.
2. go to up until you reach wineprefix folder
3. copy folders in folder wineprefix
4. after copying is done rename new folder
5. exit and open playonlinux
6. start application from new drive

unfortunately playonlinux vault is not working, does not exist any more, so you can archive the new folder with 7z or some compression software

Comment: What is the meaning of the last line?